Return value of cell from a table when conditions are met
I have a table as below
A3: ‘names’
A4:A31 list of employee names
B1:NC1 dates from 1 jan to 31 dec
B2:NC2 corresponding day of the week (Monday/tuesday…)
Whenever an employee plots a leave, I manually go and type leave in the cell for that date against that employee.
For eg, if Sam take a leave on Jan-1-24, (Sam being the first name in employee name list) I’ll type ‘leave’ in cell B4
On a different sheet in the same workbook, I am making a weekly roster table
The weekly table is as below
A1 : Skillset
A3:A30 : skillset of corresponding employee
B1 : Name
B3:B30 : names of the employees in the same order as A4:A31 of the leaves sheet
C1 : shift
C3:C30 : shift of the employee for that week
Eg: ‘10:00 - 19:00’
D1 : week off
D3:D30 : employee’s weekly off
Eg: ‘Thur - Fri’
E1:K1 : dates
Eg: 15-Apr
E2:K2 : day of the week for the date specified in E1:K1
Eg: Monday
E3:K30 : based of the week of for the employee (taken from D1:D30) it will show either ‘P’ is the employee is scheduled to work on that day, or ‘OFF’ if the employee has a weekly off on that day.
In addition to the ‘P’ and ‘Off’ I want the table to check if the employee (name mentioned in B3:B30 of the weekly roster sheet) has a leave (B4:NC31 of the yearly leaves sheet) and return a value of ‘Leave’
But unable to do so.
The problem is, I cannot reveal much details of the actual project as this is for my workplace and rest of the details are classified in a manner of speaking.
I wanted to keep this part as simple as possible when it comes to formulas, as this will serve as a base for multiple other sheets to be later connected to the same workbook.
I thought of vlookup combined with hlookup but it got too complex

You need to provide more clarity on how your data is structured with dummy examples to get a more chance of the community being able to help. If employee plots a date of leave, use the WEEKNUM function on that table to extract the week number. Then when you're pulling all the employees check using a index/match against the employee and week number to pull that they're gone that particular week. I can't say much else without seeing the epreadsheet's or information's structure.

Hello, thank you for the guidance. I am new to this and any help I get is appreciated. I have edited my question to provide more clarity on my project. Hope it helps. Thanks again

If we cannot see enough details, the question cannot be answered. If the project is classified, don't ask about it here if you aren't prepared to divulge sufficient detail to have it answered.

Match Weekly Columns

=LET(sdata,Sheet1!A1:NC6,
    monday,TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),2)+1,
    week_data,CHOOSECOLS(DROP(sdata,2),
        SEQUENCE(,7,XMATCH(monday,TAKE(sdata,1)))),
    IF(week_data="leave","leave",""))

